# Codeigniter folders for controllers

Tags: codeigniter

I would like to build a platform that contain some versions control.

Now I would like to create for each version folder inside the controller folder so I can merge all version related controllers inside.

For example controller folder:

```
1.0.0/default.php
2.0.0/default.php
3.0.0/default.php
```

(So in this example 1.0.0 is the version number and default is the controller name)

So I would like to create some routing rules so that version structure will work from URL:

http://www.mywebsite.com/1.0.0/

Any idea how to do it? also there may be more then one controller for each version for example:

```
1.0.0/default
1.0.0/login
1.0.0/member
```

here my routes info:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'default';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi, nice idea. But can your goal be achieved using [git](https://git-scm.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows inside your routes file:

```
$route['1.0.0'] = '1.0.0/default';
```

or if you want it more dynamic:

```
$route[(:version)] = "$version/default";
```

Comment: ok got it.. but how I make it dynamic.. without adding lines for each new controller inside the routing file? I also didnt understand your dynamic example...

Comment: with the dynamic method above,  the (:version) is called a wildcard, which means it matches anything you give it and returns it to the $verison variable, per example, if the url is /1.1.1 it will replace the $version variable with 1.1.1/default, and then It willl enter to the the default controller file inside the 1.1.1 folder, hope you got it!
that's the dynamic way of doing it, that way you wont be able to declare evey version in a separate line on your routes file :)

Comment: this line generate php error for me: $route[(:version)] = "$version/default";

Answer (score 0):

Use [subFolders](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#subfolders)

> When using this feature the first segment of your URI must specify the
>   folder. For example, let’s say you have a controller located here:
>
> `application/controllers/products/Shoes.php`
>
> To call the above controller your URI will look something like this:
>
> `example.com/index.php/products/shoes/show/123`